# Jquery Ajax doesnt work

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, rss

I have the following `div` in my html

```
<div class="result">loading</div>
```

**And my javascript is as follows.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
          accept: 'application/rss+xml',
          url: 'http://www.madhyamam.com/taxonomy/term/19/rss.xml',
          success: function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
         }
    });
});
```

But for some reasons.. it doesnt seems to work.

In [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esafwan/CCPRb/1/)

**XML returned(firebug):**

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{9ec69805-af82-4f95-979a-f8e68d415124} Line Number
>   1, Column 1:
>
> ^

**Solution**
**I bye-passed the problem using yahoo pipe. And it worked fine.**

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?  Is the request getting sent?  Is the callback getting called at all?

Comment: What have you tried already?  eg, do you see the request being sent in firebug?  when you put breakpoints, does the program stop at the expected places?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't make Ajax requests to URLs that have not the same domain, port and protocol as the current page. The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids it.

The most common workaround is having a server-side script that pulls the content, and serves it through Ajax.

Comment: so what can i do to pull a rss feed with javascript?

Comment: I bye-passed the problem using yahoo pipe. And it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As [Pekka mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100030/jquery-ajax-doesnt-work/7100051#7100051), we guess your problem is that Ajax cannot make request on other domain URLs. You have to use server-side script for that.

Example of small php server-side script for testing (from [Jquery Minime Feed library](http://minime.sdnetwork.hu/feed)):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);
echo file_get_contents('http://'.$url,0); 
?>
```

Then you can call something like

```
$.ajax({
    accept: 'application/rss+xml',
    url: 'http://youserver/getfeed.php?url=http://www.madhyamam.com/taxonomy/term/19/rss.xml',
});
```

---

However, it seems you want to show rss feed in your page. I went to same issue and ended using [Jquery Minime Feed library](http://minime.sdnetwork.hu/feed), which help you doing the job:

```
$('#test1').minimeFeed('http://index.hu/24ora/rss/');
```

Automatically use server-side script if needed, and produce quite nice output. See [demo here](http://sdnetwork.hu/demo/feedreader_demo.html)

Comment: I bye-passed the problem using yahoo pipe. And it worked fine.